# An example of using the 'react-leaflet' new useLeaflet() hook?

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm trying to get a reference to the leaflet object using the hook, so I can query the new map boundaries on different events (like Map.getBoundaries()). I'm pretty new to `reac-leaflet`, and this approach might be completely wrong, but this is what I've got for now...

What I'm trying to do is to get the map boundaries on each `moveend` event, if that's helpful...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you can only use the hook in a component that's inside the Map element:

```
<Map>
  <YourComponent />
</Map
```

And then inside your component you can do something like:

```js
const YourComponent = () => {
  const { map } = useLeaflet();
  const [bounds, setBounds] = React.useState({});

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const eventHandler = event => {
      setBounds(event.target.getBounds());
      doSomethingElse();
    }
    map.on("moveend", eventHandler);

    return () => {
      map.off("moveend", eventHandler); // Remove event handler to avoid creating multiple handlers
    }
  }, [setBounds, map]);

  return {
    // Use bounds for whatever you need
    <div>Lat: {bounds.lat}; long: {bounds.lng}</div>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Handler:

```
const onMoveEnd = (event) => {
 const bounds = event.target.getBounds()
 console.log(bounds)
}   
    // _northEast: LatLng {lat: 47.51470804161579, lng: 19.071493148803714}
    // _southWest: ...
```

Component:

```
<Map onmoveend={onMoveEnd}></Map>
```